# Nest.js e2e test dependency injection fails when importing services from shared libs

Tags: testing, dependency-injection, jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing

I have a nest.js monorepo and my e2e tests are failing using Test.createTestingModule() when i try to inject services from a shared libs folder. The same tests work if I import the exact same module and service from a nested folder relative to my e2e test file.

Im using the @nest/config module and service as a simple example to demonstrate that context isn't shared between e2e test app created injecting dependencies into createTestingModle() and the modules/services that it injects.

My nest monorepo structure:

```
mono-root
  - libs
    - config-test
      - node_modules (including @nest and typeorm stuff) 
      - src
        - module and service files
  - apps
    - myapp
    - node_modules (including @nest and typeorm stuff) 
    - src
      - main.ts
        - e2e-spec.ts
         -  config-test
          - identical module and service files to those in /libs but of course no 
            node_modules
```

module and service code:

in mylib/src

module

```
// config-module.ts
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { MyConfigService } from "./config-service";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [MyConfigService],
  exports: [MyConfigService],
})
export class MyConfigModule {}
```

service

```
//config-service.ts
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";

@Injectable()
export class MyConfigService {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
    console.log("MyConfigService", this.configService.get<string>("abcd"));
  }
}
```

my e2e test sits in the same location as my nest app. The console log in MyConfigService outputs undefined importing my module and service from libs but outputs the expected value when i import from the nested folder (relative to the e2e test file).

```
 config.e2e-spec.ts
import { Test } from "@nestjs/testing";
import { MyConfigModule, MyConfigService } from "@spotlightsportsgroup/nest";
// import { MyConfigModule, MyConfigService } from "./config-test/index";
import { ConfigService, ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";

describe("SharedLib", () => {
  let myConfigService: MyConfigService;
  let configService: ConfigService;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [MyConfigModule, ConfigModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [MyConfigService],
    })
      .overrideProvider(ConfigService)
      .useValue({
        get: jest.fn((value) => {
          return "mocked:" + value;
        }),
      })
      .compile();

    myConfigService = moduleRef.get<MyConfigService>(MyConfigService);
    configService = moduleRef.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);
  });
```

console.log output importing from the nested folder:

```
  console.log
    MyConfigService mocked:abcd

      at new MyConfigService (config-test/config-test/config-service.ts:8:13)

  console.log
    MyConfigService mocked:abcd
```

console.log output importing module and service from the libs folder.

```
  console.log
    MyConfigService undefined

      at new MyConfigService (config-test/config-test/config-service.ts:8:13)

  console.log
    MyConfigService undefined
```

so the question I have is: is it possible to configure my e2e test to pass context to injected services when importing from libs folder?

Answer (score 0):

This was a project specific issue caused by a misuse of npm workspace entries in the mono root. The resolution is outside the scope of the problem definition, but confirms that nest monorepos supportsimporting modules and providers from shared libs both in /apps and /libs using the patterns described in the post.